# How can I get a various number of rows while limiting the number of different ids in one SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, top-n

Let's say I have a table with two ids, series_id and match_id. The series_id can be repeated, but match_ids are unique. In addition, the number of possible match_ids per series can vary from 1 to 5. I want to select the top 10 series and all the match_ids associated with them. In other words, if I want to select the top 10 series, I could end up selecting as few as 10 match_ids or as many as 50 match_ids. How can I do that?

Edit: Here's an example list of the top 10 match ids.

```
MatchID SeriesID
250059  3155
260071  3156
260086  3163
270079  3157
270080  3157
270081  3157
340566  3123
340607  3124
350551  3123
350552  3123
```

As you can see, SeriesId repeats three times. for 3157, and at least two times for 3123.

Ideally, I'd want the following:

```
MatchID     SeriesID
1001400020      3150
1001400019      3150
1001400010      3150
270081          3157
270080          3157
270079          3157
1001320026      3151
1001320025      3151
1001320024      3151
1001320023      3151
1001320017      3151
750596          3146
750595          3146
750592          3146
750591          3146
760569          3145
760568          3145
760567          3145
760566          3145
760565          3145
760517          3144
760515          3144
760512          3144
1001380039      3131
1001380038      3131
1001380037      3131
1001380034      3131
1001310030      3128
1001310029      3128
1001300036      3128
1001370029      3130
1001370028      3130
1001370027      3130
1001370026      3130
1001370020      3130
260086          3163
```

Because in this case, the number of unique series ids is 10 in total.

Comment: also can you show an example of the data and the desired output?

Comment: match_id is unique or combination of match_id and series_id are unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable m INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT series_id 
  FROM myTable 
  ORDER BY series_id 
  LIMIT 10) t ON t.series_id = m.series_id
```

[SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4264c5/1)